# Adding Column to CSV results in blank file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add a column as the 2nd column in an existing csv, the existing file has 2 columns.

I've tried the following code but when I run it, it just generates a zero byte file with no content.  If I direct the output to another filename then it works as expected.

```
$inFile = "C:\temp\Book1.csv"

Import-Csv $inFile | Select Provider,@{N='SelectionName';E={''}},MarketType | Export-Csv $inFile -NoTypeInformation
```

what I would like as output is as follows.  i.e. include the header for the new column, but add no data

Provider,SelectionName,MarketType

ABC,,Home

Comment: in my experience, simply adding a property name - not an expression - will create a NEW, blank property if one does not already exist in the object.

Comment: Thanks Lee, indeed that does work but doesn't solve the problem that when i write back out to the same file i get a zero byte empty file.

Comment: ah! well, that is because you are using a pipeline. [*grin*] it sends one thing at a time down the pipe ... and the file is open for reading _while you are trying to write to it_.. the fix is to wrap the file read call in parens like this >>> `(Import-Csv $inFile) |` ///// however, the _sensible, safe, reliable_ method is to NEVER write to your input file. use a new file for writes and - if absolutely needed - you can destroy your source file by copying the new one to the old one. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a pipeline where you're writing the same file you're reading from you MUST ensure that reading the file has finished *before* writing starts.

If you have a statement

```
Import-Csv 'a.csv' | Export-Csv 'a.csv'
```

both operations open the file at the same time, but `Export-Csv` also truncates it (because it will be writing to the file, replacing the existing data). When `Import-Csv` then starts reading the already truncated file there's no data left to read, so no data is passed through the pipeline, and in turn nothing is written back to the file. Hence you're left with an empty file.

To avoid this behavior put the reading statement in parentheses (i.e. a subexpression):

```
(Import-Csv 'a.csv') | Export-Csv 'a.csv'
```

That ensures that the file is read first, and written to *after* reading has completed.

The downside of this approach is that all data is read into memory, which can affect system performance when you're processing large files. The workaround for that scenario is to write the output to a temporary file first, and then replace the original with the temp file:

```
Import-Csv 'a.csv' | Export-Csv 'temp.csv'
Remove-Item 'a.csv'
Move-Item 'temp.csv' 'a.csv'
```

Note that this is not limited to `Import-Csv`/`Export-Csv`. It applies to all operations where you're writing to the same file you're reading from.

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive reply.  The files in questions are small at this time (<10kB) but its something to note for future.